# Incompatible types: double[][] can not be converted to double

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to resolve an issue for this assignment I was given for Homework. I am currently stuck and would appreciate any help that could guide me in correcting the program.

The original assignment is as follows:

> Write a program that uses a two-dimensional array to store the highest and lowest temperatures for each month of the year. Write two methods : one to calculate and return the average high and one to calculate and return the average low of the year.  Your program should output all the values in the array and then output the average high and the average low.

This is the code I have assembled so far and have an error that I am not able to resolve. It is " incompatible types: converting double[][] cannot be converted to double. The lines in question are Line 8, and Line 110 ( the last return in the program).

```
import java.util.*;

public class Weather
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {

   double[][] tempData = getData();
   printTempData(tempData);  
   double avgHigh = averageHigh(tempData);
   double avgLow = averageLow(tempData);
   int indexHigh = indexHighTemp(tempData);
   int indexLow= indexLowTemp(tempData);

   System.out.format("The average high temperature is %4.1f%n", avgHigh);
   System.out.format("The average low temperature is %4.1f%n", avgLow);
   System.out.format("The index of high temperature is %2d%n", indexHigh);
   System.out.format("The index of low temperature is %2d%n", indexLow);

  }

 private static void printTempData(double[][] tempData)
  {
    System.out.format("%6s:%4s%4s%4s%4s%4s%4s%4s%4s%4s%4s%4s%4s%n","Month","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
    System.out.format("%6s:","Low");

   for (int i = 0; i < tempData[0].length;i++)
   {
    System.out.format("%4.1s", tempData[0][i]);
   }
  System.out.format("%n");
  System.out.format("%6s: ","High"); 
   for (int i = 0; i < tempData[1].length; i++)
   {
     System.out.format("%4.1f", tempData[1][i]);
   }
  System.out.format("%n");
}

private static int indexLowTemp(double[][] tempData)
 {
  int index = 0;
  double temp = tempData[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < tempData[0].length; i++)
     {
        if (temp > tempData[0][i])
           { 
            temp = tempData[0][i];
            index = i;
            }
      }
       return index +1;
 }

private static int indexHighTemp(double[][] tempData)
  {
  int index = 0;
  double temp = tempData[1][0];
     for(int i = 0; i< tempData[1].length; i++)
        {
         if ( temp < tempData[1][i])
           {
            temp = tempData[1][i];
            index = i;
           }
        }

        return index + 1;
  }

 private static double averageHigh(double[][] tempData)
  {
   double avg = 0.0;
     for(int i=0; i < tempData[0].length; i++)
       {
        avg += tempData[0][i];
       }

     avg /= tempData[0].length;

     return avg;
  }

  private static double averageLow(double[][] tempData)
   {
   double avg = 0.0;
     for(int i=0; i > tempData[1].length; i++)
       {
        avg += tempData[0][i];
       }

     avg /= tempData[0].length;

     return avg;
  }


 private static double getData()
 {
  double[][] tempData = new double[2][12];
  Random r = new Random();

     for (int j = 0; j < tempData[0].length; j++)
     {
        tempData[0][j] = 30 + Math.sqrt(j) - r.nextDouble();
        tempData[1][j] = 30 + Math.sqrt(j) + r.nextDouble();
     }

    return tempData;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already declared an array

```
      double[][] tempData = getData();
```

but you are trying to call

```
       private static double getData()
```

thus the error "converting double[][] cannot be converted to double."

Hence change to

```
       private static double[][] getData()
```

Answer (score 6):

Your method `private static double getData()` should be `private static double[][] getData()`

Answer (score 1):

The method should be `private static double[][] getData()`